# How to melt a selected single column in a data frame

Tags: r, reshape, melt

With this code:

```
dat <- structure(list(Probes = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1415670_at",
"1415671_at", "1415672_at", "1415673_at", "1415674_a_at", "1415675_at"
), class = "factor"), Genes = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L,
3L), .Label = c("Atp6v0d1", "Copg1", "Dpm2", "Golga7", "Psph",
"Trappc4"), class = "factor"), FOO = c(1.133, 1.068,
1.01, 0.943, 1.048, 1.053)), .Names = c("Probes", "Genes", "FOO"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I created the following data frame:

```
        Probes    Genes   FOO
1   1415670_at    Copg1 1.133
2   1415671_at Atp6v0d1 1.068
3   1415672_at   Golga7 1.010
4   1415673_at     Psph 0.943
5 1415674_a_at  Trappc4 1.048
6   1415675_at     Dpm2 1.053
```

What I want to do is to select last column and melt it into like this:

```
FOO 1.133 
FOO 1.068 
FOO 1.010 
FOO 0.943 
FOO 1.048 
FOO 1.053
```

How can I do that?

I'm stuck with this code:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(dat[,ncol(dat)])
```

Comment: What is the expected output? A data.frame with 2 columns? A data.frame with 1 column + row names? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `stack` after selecting the 'FOO' column.

```
stack(dat['FOO'])
```

Or

```
melt(dat['FOO'])
```

The `dat[,'FOO']` is not a `data.frame`.  It is a `vector`.  We can find the difference between `[`, `[[` etc in the `?Extract`.  When there is a single column, the default option with `[` is `drop=TRUE`.   We can specify `drop=FALSE` if we are using the `,` to specify the row index.

```
stack(dat[, "FOO", drop=FALSE])
```

If we don't know the column name, just use `ncol`

```
stack(dat[ncol(dat)])
```

The difference is in how we are using it and the object returned.

Comment: Let's say I don't know 'FOO', I'd like to select *last column* only. How can I modify your code to use index.

Comment: @neversaint also note that stack will work for characters and numerics or a combination but not factors which you have in your example

Comment: @rawr - which I might add is really quite sensible - not allowing the combining of categorical values which might look the same but mean entirely different things is a smart design choice.